# Python - time series alignment and "to date" functions

Tags: python, date, alignment, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset with the following first three columns.
Include Basket ID (unique identifier), Sale amount (dollars) and date of the transaction. I want to calculate the following column for each row of the dataset, and I would like to it in Python.

**Previous Sale** of the same basket (if any); **Sale Count** to date for current basket; **Mean To Date** for current basket (if available); **Max To Date** for current basket (if available)

```
Basket  Sale   Date       PrevSale SaleCount MeanToDate MaxToDate
88      $15 3/01/2012                1      
88      $30 11/02/2012      $15      2         $23        $30
88      $16 16/08/2012      $30      3         $20        $30
123     $90 18/06/2012               1      
477     $77 19/08/2012               1      
477     $57 11/12/2012      $77      2         $67        $77
566     $90 6/07/2012                1
```

I'm pretty new with Python, and I really struggle to find anything to do it in a fancy way. I've sorted the data (as above) by BasketID and Date, so I can get the previous sale in bulk by shifting forward by one for each single basket. No clue how to get the MeanToDate and MaxToDate in an efficient way apart from looping... any ideas?

Comment: What format is your current 'dataset' in (the three first columns)?  Is it a file or are you using some sort of data structure currently?

Comment: sorry, i've forgot to mention. it come from a text file, but is stored in a pandas' dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
from pandas import concat
from pandas.stats.moments import expanding_mean, expanding_count

def handler(grouped):
    se = grouped.set_index('Date')['Sale'].sort_index()
    # se is the (ordered) time series of sales restricted to a single basket
    # we can now create a dataframe by combining different metrics
    # pandas has a function for each of the ones you are interested in!
    return  concat(
        {
            'MeanToDate': expanding_mean(se), # cumulative mean
            'MaxToDate': se.cummax(),         # cumulative max
            'SaleCount': expanding_count(se), # cumulative count
            'Sale': se,                       # simple copy
            'PrevSale': se.shift(1)           # previous sale
        },
        axis=1
     )

# we then apply this handler to all the groups and pandas combines them
# back into a single dataframe indexed by (Basket, Date)
# we simply need to reset the index to get the shape you mention in your question
new_df = df.groupby('Basket').apply(handler).reset_index()
```

You can read more about grouping/aggregating [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html).

Comment: The cumulative function are just awesome - Thanks! Why the assumption of not having more than one transaction per basket per day?

Comment: If the index isn't unique `concat` won't be able to align the columns properly back together since there will be multiple values for some  indices, if that makes sense.

Comment: make sense...and unfortunately there are multiple dates for the same basket. When you're suggesting to use resample, is it within the "handler" or before for the dataframe? I hope i've been asking something that make sense, as it not really clear what resample is actually doing (need to get back home first!)

Comment: Having checked on an example, it seems to work also for duplicate indices. `concat` apparently aligns data with the same index in the order they appear. I edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: you're the man, this is all great, powerful and superquick...it took 5 sec to process over 300k rows - thanks heaps!

just last thing, why the reset_index at the bottom? i can't appreciate any difference between using it or no.. am i missing something?

Comment: Glad to hear. You don't have to use `reset_index`: if you don't the `Basket` and `Date` columns will just be in the index (and not in the 'proper' table data). Your example shows them as normal columns, `reset_index` does that for you (plus it allows you to go back to having a unique index).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__  # u'0.24.2'

from pandas import concat

def handler(grouped):
    se = grouped.set_index('Date')['Sale'].sort_index()
    return  concat(
        {
            'MeanToDate': se.expanding().mean(),   # cumulative mean
            'MaxToDate': se.expanding().max(),  # cumulative max
            'SaleCount': se.expanding().count(),   # cumulative count
            'Sale': se,                # simple copy
            'PrevSale': se.shift(1)   # previous sale
        },
        axis=1
     )

###########################
from datetime import datetime  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Basket':[88,88,88,123,477,477,566],
                  'Sale':[15,30,16,90,77,57,90],
                  'Date':[datetime.strptime(ds,'%d/%m/%Y') 
                          for ds in ['3/01/2012','11/02/2012','16/08/2012','18/06/2012',
                                    '19/08/2012','11/12/2012','6/07/2012']]})
#########

new_df = df.groupby('Basket').apply(handler).reset_index()
```